# Workbench module without taxonomy vocab

Tags: taxonomy-terms, workbench

Is there a way to use a workbench module for workflowing purposes without having any taxonomy vocabularies defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Workbench Moderation](http://drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation) module allows you to define workflow states for your content, and does not require Taxonomy.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too vague. [Workbench](http://drupal.org/project/workbench) is a Suite of modules: Moderation, Access, Files, Media ...

Workbench Access can work with Taxonomies or Menu hierarchies.

Currently Workbench only works with data whose base type is a `Node` it does not work with custom `Entities` you may use on your site.